# What is my CPU speed?

Tags: linux, performance

I need the CPU speed of my KVM host.

When I am using dmidecode, the result is the following :

> sudo dmidecode  | egrep "Max Speed|Current Speed"
>
> Max Speed: 3100 MHz
>
> Current Speed: 3100 MHz

Whereas, when I am using lscpu,  the result is:

> lscpu | grep "MHz".
>
> CPU MHz:               1600.000

So, why there are two different values, and between the two, which is my actual CPU speed?

Additional :

When the /proc/cpuinfo file has the following result for the speed of the individual cores.

> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz"
>
> cpu MHz       : 1600.000
>
> cpu MHz       : 1600.000
>
> cpu MHz       : 1600.000
>
> cpu MHz       : 1600.000

Can anybody explain in details?

Comment: Try doing the same measures with some process actively running on the CPU (e.g. an infinite *while* loop, a complex compilation, etc...)

Comment: Might be easier to check your bios information... Either way, this seems like a question better suited for SuperUser than for StackOverflow, as it doesn't seem to be programming related.

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo may give some info, but yes, SuperUser is better suited since you may need cpupower/governor

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU has a rated speed of 3.1GHz. At the time you checked `cpuinfo`, it was running at 1.6GHz. When load is low, the CPU runs at a lower speed to save energy and keep itself cooler.

Comment: But one thing I didn't understand, why the "current speed" value in dmidecode is showing 3100 MHz.It should show 1600 Mhz, right?

Comment: The `dmidecode` command likely requires enough CPU power to bring the CPU speed up.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `cpufreq` running, the driver which reduces CPU frequency during inactivity periods, you may take maximum frequency from it (in KHz):

```
$ cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/
$ sudo cat cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
2363000
$ cat cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
2600000
```

Note that 2,6 GHz is Intel "Turbo" frequency of my CPU, actual stock frequency is 1,7 MHz.